# Maximal ideals in the ring of eventually constant sequences of real numbers

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

For homework I am studying the ring $R$ of eventually constant sequences of real numbers (with multiplication and addition defined componentwise).

What are the maximal ideals of $R$?

By looking at surjective homomorphisms it is easy to find maximal ideals, but I haven't been able to give a thorough characterization. Below are the maximal ideals I have identified.

Let $s$ be some sequence in $R$. Denote by $\bar{s}$ the real number to which $s$ converges and denote by $s_i$ the $i$-th element in $s$.

For each $i \in \mathbb{N}$ define the homomorphism
$$\varphi_i \colon R \to \mathbb{R}$$
which maps $s$ to $s_i$. $\varphi_i$ is surjective so its kernel is a maximal ideal. The kernel of $\varphi_i$ is the ideal of sequences with $i$-th component zero.

Also define the homomorphism
$$\varphi \colon R \to \mathbb{R}$$
which maps $s$ to $\bar{s}$. $\varphi$ is also surjective and its kernel is the ideal of sequences that converge to 0. Mapping $s$ to $\bar{s} - r$ for $r\in \mathbb{R}$ seems to yield more maximal ideals.

Are there any others and how can I show there aren't other ideals once I've found all the ideals?

Thank You

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "Mapping $s$ to $\overline s - r$ for $r \in \mathbb R$ seems to yield more maximal ideals."

Comment: Shifting the image of $\varphi$ by $r$ for some real number $r$.

Comment: That shift would not give you a homomorphism any longer (it would not even send $0$ to $0$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you've found them all.  Let's call $\mathfrak m_i$ the ideal of $s$ with $s_i = 0$ and $\mathfrak m_\infty$ the $s$ with $\overline s = 0$.  What you want to do is assume you have a maximal $\mathfrak m$ such that $\mathfrak m \neq \mathfrak m_i$ for any finite $i$ and then show that this implies $\mathfrak m = \mathfrak m_\infty$.

Let $e_i$ be the sequence with a $1$ in the $i^\text{th}$ position and zero's elsewhere.  If $\mathfrak m \neq \mathfrak m_i$ then there's an element in $\mathfrak m$ that has an $a \neq 0$ in the $i^\text{th}$ position.  Multiply that element by $\frac1a e_i$ to get that $e_i$ is in $\mathfrak m$ for all $i$.

Now assume $\mathfrak m$ contains an $s$ such that $\overline s \neq 0$.  Use the $e_i$ to show that this would imply that $1 \in \mathfrak m$.

**Edit:** As rschwieb suggests, you can also observe that an element is a unit iff it's nonzero at every spot in the sequence, so one can also show that there's a unit in $\mathfrak m$ instead of jumping straight to showing that $1 \in \mathfrak m$.

Comment: +1 I posted an answer but eventually decided that it didn't differ significantly enough from yours :) The one thing I would add to this is to "think about what the units of the ring look like" in order to facilitate the last step you outlined.

Comment: @rschwieb I did this problem earlier and got the same characterization but I can’t figure out why we need the hypothesis that the sequences are eventually constant?

Comment: @PrinceM You must settle in the ring you are talking about before you ask questions about it.  It is not a matter of that condition “being necessary” or not.  It simply is part of the context.

Comment: Uh sure. Still seems weird that the original author of the question included it if it has no impact to the question. I’m not saying it’s mathematically a problem, more of a “contextually unusual” situation.

Comment: You’re telling me you don’t think it would be a little weird if someone assigned a problem “prove that every number less than 10 can be factored as a product of primes”

Comment: @PrinceM no what you’re asking is like, facing the question “prove every element of $\mathbb Z$ factors into primes” and asking “yes but why is $\mathbb Z$ necessary?”  In fact it isn’t.  You could have started with any PID.  In this Question, choosing this ring results in these maximal ideals.  You could ask the same question about any other given ring and gotten different results.

Comment: Except that primality in the integers was a concept way before the general notion of a PID and rings and prime ideals were literally meant to generalize the original notions.. The two rings I’m mentioning exist in the same time frame.. one ring isn’t intentionally a generalization of the other. But the fact that no part of anything used in the proofs regarding this ring requires the sequences to become constant seems to imply that they are basically the same rings.. or atleast have a correspondence between ideals so they would be the same in the algebro-geometric picture.

Comment: Still seems like a weird and unusual criteria to add to the problem

Comment: @rschwieb I think I see now where I was mistaken. I have a couple questions: 1. The ring of real valued sequences ostensibly could have more maximal ideals. For example the alternating sequence 1,0,1,... could possibly generate a maximal ideal, yes? Our problem above is more self contained because we need not consider these cases.

Comment: @rschwieb 2. In the first line of the solution above it reads "$\mathfrak{m}_\infty$ the $s$ with $\overline{s} = 0$". I presume this means to say "$\mathfrak{m}_\infty$ the ideal of $s$ with $\overline{s} = 0$", but if I am not mistaken the ideal of sequences that eventually become 0 is not finitely generated, no? So it does not quite make sense to talk about $\mathfrak{m}_\infty$ as the "ideal of a certain element $s$". I do not think this changes the validity of the rest of the solution, but I think the statement is not quite right. I suppose that also means the ring is not Noetherian?

Comment: @rschwieb maybe when Jim says "the ideal of" he does not mean ideal generated by and just "the ideal that contains all $s$ with that property.

Comment: @PrinceM: Yes, $\mathfrak m_\infty$ is the ideal containing all $s$ such that $\overline s = 0$.  Incidentally, this would not be an ideal if not for the condition that the sequences are eventually constant, so that's what you need that hypothesis for.

Comment: Thanks! @Jim. Does it fail to be a group? In the ring of real valued sequences the set $\mathfrak{m}_\infty$ seems to still contain all products $ r\cdot s$ for $r \in R$. So if it fails to be an ideal I suppose it must fail to be a group, but I don't immediatley see why that would be

Comment: @PrinceM, sorry that was a typo.  I meant to say it would not be *a maximal* ideal.  It is indeed an ideal, but without the condition that all sequences are eventually constant it is not maximal.  For example, it is properly contained in the ideal of all sequences that are eventually 0 at even indexes.

Comment: That makes sense @Jim , I thought maybe that was what you meant. Thank you for your responses.